# Java - java.lang.Error: SWT Resource was not properly disposed

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I am getting back into using the JAVA programming language. To reintroduce myself, I am writing a simple banking program with unit tests to adjust to the syntax. I am having trouble getting the code to compile as I am seeing an error I have not seen before.

```
java.lang.Error: SWT Resource was not properly disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.initNonDisposeTracking(Resource.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.<init>(Resource.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.createShadow(CTabRendering.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.setShadowColor(CTabRendering.java:1054)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.dom.CTabFolderElement.reset(CTabFolderElement.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.engine.AbstractCSSSWTEngineImpl.reset(AbstractCSSSWTEngineImpl.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.setTheme(ThemeEngine.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngine.setTheme(ThemeEngine.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ViewsPreferencePage.performOk(ViewsPreferencePage.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$7.run(PreferenceDialog.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.okPressed(PreferenceDialog.java:889)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.okPressed(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.buttonPressed(PreferenceDialog.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
```

I did a lot of research on Google and have yet to find a solution. Does anyone have an idea as to why I am getting this error twice in my error log?

I am using the Eclipse IDE. Here is my code:

BankAccount.java:

```
package simplebank;

public class BankAccount {

    private double balance;
    
    public BankAccount()
    {
        balance = 0;
    }
    
    public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
    {
        balance = initialBalance;
    }
    
    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
    
    boolean deposit(double amount)  
    {
        
        if(amount > 0 && balance - amount > 0)
        {   
            balance = balance + amount;
            return true; 
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean withdrawl(double amount)
    {
        if (amount > 0)
        {   
            balance = balance - amount;
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean transfer(BankAccount transferTo, double amount)
    {
        
        if (amount > 0)
        {
            if(this.withdrawl(amount))
            {
                if(transferTo.deposit(amount))
                {
                    
                }
                else // Return bank account to normal 
                {
                    this.deposit(amount);
                    return false;
                }
            }   
            
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

BankAccountTest.java

```
package simplebank;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class BankAccountTest {

    BankAccount account1  = null;
    BankAccount account2 = null;
    @BeforeAll
    public void setup() {
        account1 = new BankAccount(20.00);
        account2 = new BankAccount();
    }
    
    @Test
    void testGetBalance() {
        assert(account1.getBalance() == 20.00);
    }

    @Test
    void testDeposit() {
        account1.deposit(20);
        assert(account1.getBalance() == 40.00);
    }

    @Test
    void testWithdrawl() {
        account1.withdrawl(10);
        assert(account1.getBalance() == 30.00);
    }

    @Test
    void testTransfer() {
        account1.transfer(account2, 10);
        assert(account1.getBalance() == 20.00);
        assert(account2.getBalance() == 10.00);
    }
}
```

As a side note, if anyone has any recommendations on how I could improve this simple code, please do leave your suggestions! I am just now getting back into JAVA so my style may not be the best.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Eclipse and not really anything to do with your code

Answer (score 6):

In Eclipse 4.19 (2021-03) an API to track proper resource disposal has been added, see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.19/platform_isv.php#resource-disposal-tracking

This is where these errors come from.

Try to set in your eclipse.ini from `true` to `false`
`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true`
to get rid of them. Not sure it will work.

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: I have a similar issue with jface.wizard.WizardDialog / WizardPage, which does not dispose the image it creates properly.  Your solution just tells RCP to be silent, but of course it does not resolve the problem being resources leaking. Setting the flag also hides these traces where it is really the developers fault.

Comment: You are correct, that this flag only hides the problem. But the code of OP doesn't do any RCP related stuff. Essentially Eclipse itself is spamming the log with internal warning messages. The Eclipse developers are responsible for getting rid of those problems (incl. your WizardPage example)

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with a variety of code examples, I changed my test file to contain the following code:

```
package simplebank;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import junit.framework.ComparisonFailure;

class BankAccountTest {
    BankAccount account1  = null;
    BankAccount account2 = null;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        account1 = new BankAccount(20.00);
        account2 = new BankAccount();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception {
        account1 = null;
        account2 = null;
    }

    @Test
    void testGetBalance() {
        assert(account1.getBalance() == 20.00);
    }
    
    void testDeposit() {
        account1.deposit(20);
        assert(account1.getBalance() == 40.00);
    }
    
    @Test
    void testWithdrawl() {
        account1.withdrawl(10);
        assert(account1.getBalance() == 10.00);
    }
    
    @Test
    void testTransfer() {
        account1.transfer(account2, 10);
        assert(account1.getBalance() == 10.00);
        assert(account2.getBalance() == 10.00);
    }
}
```

It now compiles and runs all tests. The difference is I now user @BeforeEach and @AfterEach instead of @BeforeAll. The other difference is also the fact that each before and after function includes a throws Exception in the declaration. I have not tried it with the @BeforeAll function with the throw Exception added as the @BeforeEach suited my purpose. My best guess is that the absence of the "throws Exception" statement was causing the above error. I hope this helps someone else resolve this issue in the future.

Comment: I dont think this has to do anything with your code but rather with issue with eclipse.  I am seeing same and I use @BeforeEach